# Create a Span from multiple slices

Tags: c#, arrays, .net-core

Is it currently possible to create a `Span<T>` (and related types) based on multiple slices of another span?

What I'm trying to achieve is a type of multi-substring.

Consider the following array of chars:

```
[M][y][ ][b][r][i][l][l][i][a][n][t][ ][s][e][n][t][e][n][c][e]
```

I'd like to assemble a new sentence based on a list of ranges.

`var newSentence = Span.MultiSlice(originalSentence, new List<(int start, int length)> { (3, 5), (13, 4) })`

Should result in a `ReadOnlySpan<char>` that represents `brillsent`.

Also would it be possible to assemble this `Span` by slicing from different spans, instead of just the one `originalSentence`, as in the above example?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is by-definition:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.span-1?view=netcore-3.0

> Provides a type- and memory-safe representation of **a contiguous region** of arbitrary memory.

Your intended use-case breaks `Span<T>`'s contract because you aren't representing a single contiguous address space.

It sounds like you just want an `IEnumerable<Char>` that operates over a series of slices:

```
using OneOf; // https://github.com/mcintyre321/OneOf

using Run = OneOf<String,Span<Char>,IEnumerable<Char>>;

public class CompositeString
{
    private readonly List<Run> runs = new List<Run>();

    public void Add( String str ) => this.runs.Add( str );
    public void Add( Span<Char> span ) => this.runs.Add( span );
    public void Add( IEnumerable<Char> chars ) => this.runs.Add( chars ); 

    public void WriteTo( TextWriter wtr )
    {
        foreach( Run run in this.runs )
        {
            run.Switch(
                ( String s ) => wtr.Write( s ),
                ( Span<Char> span ) =>
                { // Span<T> doesn't implement IEnumerable<T>, but you can still use it with a `foreach`:
                    foreach( Char c in span ) wtr.Write( c );
                },
                ( IEnumerable<Char> chars ) =>
                {
                    foreach( Char c in chars ) wtr.Write( c );
                },
            );
        }
    }

    public override void ToString()
    {
        using( StringWriter wtr = new StringWriter() )
        {
            this.WriteTo( wtr );
            return wtr.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Are you aware that `OneOf<String,Span<Char>,IEnumerable<Char>>` isn't possible because `Span` can't be used as a type argument?

Comment: @silkfire No, I didn't know that - sorry (I've been stuck on .NET Framework, so I haven't had a chance to use `Span<T>` in .NET Core).

Answer (score 0):

This solves exactly the same issue - https://blog.ndepend.com/improve-c-code-performance-with-spant/

Slicing an array and working with span made out of those slices.

There is also benchmark saying span is faster than `string.Split`

```
   static void GetUIntArrayWithSpan(string commaSeparatedUInt, uint[] arrayToFill) {
      // View the string as a span, so we can slice it in loop
      ReadOnlySpan<char> span = commaSeparatedUInt.AsSpan();
      int nextCommaIndex = 0;
      int insertValAtIndex = 0;
      bool isLastLoop = false;
      while (!isLastLoop) {
         int indexStart = nextCommaIndex;
         nextCommaIndex = commaSeparatedUInt.IndexOf(',', indexStart);
 
         isLastLoop = (nextCommaIndex == -1);
         if (isLastLoop) {
            nextCommaIndex = commaSeparatedUInt.Length; // Parse last uint
         }
 
         // Get a slice of the string that contains the next uint...
         ReadOnlySpan<char> slice = span.Slice(indexStart, nextCommaIndex - indexStart);
         // ... and parse it
         uint valParsed = uint.Parse(slice);
 
         // Then insert valParsed in arrayToFill
         arrayToFill[insertValAtIndex] = valParsed;
         insertValAtIndex++;
 
         // Skip the comma for next iteration
         nextCommaIndex++; 
      }
```